# Use Network Load Balancer with a Kubernetes Cluster in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to set up a OKE Cluster on OCI, deploy a Ghost container in it for blogging, then expose it to the internet.
I've successfully done it with a load balancer service in my YAML and my blog is visible to the internet:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blog
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/oci-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/oci-load-balancer-tls-secret: ssl-certificate-secret
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: x.x.x.x
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: blog
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 443
    targetPort: 2368
```

which provisioned a new Load Balancer of shape 100Mbps in OCI. The problem is that it costs quite a bit.
In OCI, there are two types of load balancer:

[image]

and the second one (Network Load Balancer) is free.
So the question is, how do i use the second type (Network Load Balancer) with a Kubernetes Cluster in OCI? Is there any other way of exposing my Ghost container pod to the internet? I've read somewhere about creating a NodePort but not sure if it works in OCI and don't really understand it.
Any clue is welcome.   Thank you!

Comment: Did you see [this article](https://k21academy.com/1z0-1072/flexible-network-load-balancer/)? Is it helpful?

Comment: I did see it. It's basically the same as the official docs. I've tried creating a NodePort service in my Kubernetes cluster, then a Network Load Balancer with the worker node as a Backend. Security Lists have been config, but still i can't access my blog from outside. And even if that works, a NodePort can only take port > 30000 so it won't serve my blog at 443 as normal.

Answer (score 3):

OKE now supports OCI Network Load Balancers (NLB). The documentation is available at: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengcreatingloadbalancer.htm.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31341696)

Answer (score 2):

I am part of the product team for OKE.
OKE does not support OCI Network Load Balancer (NLB) yet. However, we are working on it.
For the time being, you can provision an NLB manually and load balance across worker nodes as the article mentioned above describes.

Comment: Hi @gregvers, not trying to be pushy here, just wanted to bring your attention to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893487/kubernetes-nodeport-is-not-available-on-all-nodes-oracle-cloud-infrastructure